# Is it really necessary take one entire week to rest from running?

Tags: running, recovery, workout-routines

Ok, 
first of all I know there is a similar question [Here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/481/is-it-necessary-to-have-a-rest-week), but it is more related to muscle workout (if it's a duplicate please close that without problem)

I started run seriously in april, before that I trained myself in a bad bad way (few days and few kms), then the competition came and I barerly finished it...

After that I decided to be coached by a personal trainer, and from april to now I have done a lot of improvements.

In april 55' to run 10km now only 40'20", I'm very satisfied...

I had a very tough practice until these months even in the summer with 35° C, I did training 5 times a week, and during lastest week I was a little tired..

Now I finished a "period" of training and PT told me to rest for an entire week without a single run...

In my opinion is too much time, but probably I'm wrong and I think that only because I don't want to lose some of the improvements that I got until now...

EDIT:
I spoke with my PT yesterday and he told me that I'll have two week for resting, first, as I said, completly without run, the second week only 3 workout
1) slow run 7km
2) medium run 6km
3) slow run 1km + fast run 4km

I think I'll die... :(

Answer (score 3):

Resting a week won't cause any *significant* losses in fitness gains, and it's critical to let the body recharge. The nature of those 5x/week sessions determines what kind of rest/recovery would be needed.

If you can't *bear* to be inactive for a week (I can't), do *really* low-intensity trots, or just walk briskly--your body will thank you, and you might be surprised at how you feel when you start up again.

Comment: Do you have any links to articles on the effects of resting periods? It might also be relevant as an answer to [my question about how much time can I put in between runs in off periods.](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11918/what-is-the-least-i-need-to-run-to-maintain-my-strength)

Answer (score 2):

Different plans and different trainers will make a rest week mean different things. Plus they also can mean different things based on what you just accomplished.

A rest week during training for me is dropping my mileage by [10-20%](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/2/2_1/107.shtml) and running at a slower pace. I might end up taking longer walks with the dog/family.

A rest week after a long race [marathon/ultra] is to not run, but normally walk. Hal Higdon has a [plan](http://www.halhigdon.com/postmarathon/zeroweek0.html) for that.

The rest week is basically time for your body to recover, you put your muscles through a lot and they need time to rebuild. Some freaks can run without rests, look at [Mike Wardian](http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/2/2_1/107.shtml) who ran a 50 miler [5h 33min] two weeks ago and just finished 2nd at a marathon on Sunday [2h 23min].

Comment: Or those "century a week" types, but I can't even imagine them running too much in-between. Yikes.