# What are the pros and cons of training running just one day per week (18k-22k)?

Tags: running, health, injury, jogging, half-marathon

I usually do a long run every sunday, something beetween 18 and 22k, I am just starting training for runnning, so I woluld like to know the pros and cons of just training one day per week. 
I mean pros and cons in health, not in the performance of the activity or anything else.

Comment: This question is similar to [my question about running once a week](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11918/what-is-the-least-i-need-to-run-to-maintain-my-conditioning) - you might want to check it out.