# Taking a week off from couch to 5k

Tags: running, couchto5k

There's a related question here: [Is it really necessary take one entire week to rest from running?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/is-it-really-necessary-take-one-entire-week-to-rest-from-running) but it seems like that person was already a seasoned runner.

I'm going from almost zero physical exertion for the past 4-5 years and I'm in week 4 of the c25k app. There's some stuff I have to deal with this week and I'd like to take a week off to focus on it before getting back to running. I don't want to lose the progress I've made over the past 3 weeks so is it okay to take a break? I'm relatively fit so I don't have any health issues or anything and I'm doing it purely as a hobby type thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, yes, you should be fine, but you're going to have to gauge it for yourself. Try for week 5 once you start back up, but keep in mind the week 4 goals, and switch to them if you find that week 5 is too challenging.

Answer (score 3):

Life happens to all of us, so if you have to take a break, do it.  You have little to lose by taking a week off from a running perspective.  Just make sure you have a reasonable plan to resume and maintain your fitness.  I've found that with running, consistency is key for progress.  If you let one week off become 2 and then 3, it will be much harder to get back out there. An alternative would be to put your specific training plan on hold for a week, but still do whatever running works for you.  If you can squeeze 1 workout in during the week, that may make it easier to resume your plan right where you left off.